# overwrite hdfs directory Sqoop import

Tags: sqoop

Is it possible to overwrite HDFS directory automatically instead of overwriting it every time manually while Sqoop import? 
(Do we have any option like "--overwrite" like we have for hive import "--hive-overwrite")

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `--delete-target-dir`

​It will delete `<HDFS-target-dir>` provided in command before writing data to this directory.

Comment: Hello, How we can deal this with sqoop with hcatalog integration. I know that we have a way to truncate the table before sqoop import.

Answer (score 6):

Use this: `--delete-target-dir`

This will work for overwriting the hdfs directory using sqoop syntax:

```
$ sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname --username username -P --table tablename --delete-target-dir --target-dir '/targetdirectorypath' -m 1
```

E.g:

```
$ sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/abc --username root -P --table empsqooptargetdel --delete-target-dir --target-dir '/tmp/sqooptargetdirdelete' -m 1
```

This command will refresh the corresponding hdfs directory or hive table data with updated/fresh data, every time this command is run.